# Can't set ListItem value to "" in asp.net 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have recently started coding in VS2012 and found strange behaviour of ListItem value.

In VS2010, i can set ListItem Value to "" but in VS2012 it removes Value property if its "". It is causing RequiredFieldValidator not to validate dropdown list. In VS2010 it works fine but in VS2012 it is not showing RequiredFieldValidator error message.

**IN VS2010**

```
<asp:ListItem Text="-- Choose --" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rddlValue" ValidationGroup="ClientAdd" 
          ControlToValidate="ddlValue" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="required" 
          ErrorMessage="* Required" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**IN VS2012**

```
<asp:ListItem Text="-- Choose --" ></asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: I've used 2012 for a while, and have never seen such behavior. What are you editing in, designer view? I always edit in source view, so I cannot say for sure if it is a designer issue. Also, what update do you have? 1,2,3,4?

Comment: I am updating in normal aspx page. what do you mean by update?

Comment: I mean, update for visual studio, 1-4, update 4 is the latest